# A simplified definition and examples of prime radical of a non-commutative ring

Tags: noncommutative-algebra

please provide a definition and some examples of prime radical (or Baer-McCoy radical or lower nilradical) of a non-commutative ring.please be specific.

Comment: Specific *about what*?

Answer (score 5):

The prime radical of a ring is defined to be the intersection of all prime ideals in the ring.

It is the smallest [semiprime ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime_ideal) of the ring. A ring is semiprime iff it has a zero prime radical.

This is equivalent to the nilradical for commutative rings, but this is not the case for all rings. **For example**, in a matrix ring $M_n(F)$ over a field $F$ with $n>1$, there are nonzero nilpotent elements, and yet the prime radical is zero. However, if one defines [strongly nilpotent elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/400502/29335), then you can show that the prime radical is the largest ideal whose elements are all strongly nilpotent.

The prime radical is always contained in the Jacobson radical since the Jacobson radical is the intersection of [right primitive ideals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_ideal), all of which are prime ideals. Of course they do not have to be equal. We already know a nonfield local domain provides an example (commutative or not), but here is **another example** which has a nonzero prime radical:

Take the upper triangular matrices $T_2(D)$ over a nonfield local domain $D$. Let $M$ be the unique maximal right ideal of $D$. Then the prime radical of $T_2(D)$ is the set $\begin{bmatrix}0&D\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, but the Jacobson radical is the set $\begin{bmatrix}M&D\\0&M\end{bmatrix}$.

You may notice, though, that (several formulations of) the [Artin-Wedderburn theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin-Wedderburn_theorem) demonstrate that the prime radical and Jacobson radical coincide for right (or left) Artinian rings.

Comment: thanks, plz suggest prime radicals in the case of quaternions and endomorphism rings

Comment: @ujjwal The prime radical of any simple ring (such as the quaternions or the endomorphism ring of a finite dimensional vector space) is $\{0\}$ and any of the rings I gave above are endomorphism rings of their regular modules. If you have something else in mind, you'll have to be more specific about what you want. You haven't made any requests so far that this solution does not already provide. Regards